# How to identify a number is available in a range of numbers in 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have a table with 2 columns a and b. I want to write a query to search a number is available in the column or the number falls between those 2 columns. I tried using >=,<= also with between but it is not returning any result.

Could someone help me with the query?

- If the input parameter is 1, it should return true.
- If the input parameter is 3, it should return true.
- If the input parameter is 7, it should return true.
- If the input parameter is 15, it should return false.

Thanks

Table with values and expected output:

[image: Table with values and expected output]

Comment: The answer might be product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You question history shows a series of post that seem like a XY-Problem: Auto-generated sequence id values are not meant to be without gaps and if any of your business logic relies on a specific meaning of a sequence id order it is likely a anti-pattern.

Comment: Agree with @Filburt, what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a couple of tables like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE number_ranges (
    A INT,
    B INT
);

INSERT INTO number_ranges (A, B) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 10), (20, 100);

CREATE TABLE search_inputs (
    `Search(Input)` INT
);

INSERT INTO search_inputs (`Search(Input)`) VALUES (1), (3), (7), (15);
```

You can use `BETWEEN`, `CASE`, and  `EXISTS` to achieve your desired output:

```
SELECT 
    si.`Search(Input)`,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
                 SELECT 1 
                 FROM number_ranges nr 
                 WHERE si.`Search(Input)` BETWEEN nr.A AND nr.B
             )
        THEN 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
    END AS Output
FROM search_inputs si;
```

**Output:**

| Search(Input) | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 7 | TRUE |
| 15 | FALSE |

Comment: No need for additional rand value conditions `when` between is used.

Comment: Hi @Sash Sinha, Thanks a lot. The query is working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh fixed thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server answer:

```
select max(case when yournumber between A and B then 'true' else 'false' end)
from tablename
```

ANSI/ISO SQL answer:

```
select max(yournumber between A and B) from tablename
```

If yournumber is equal to A or B, or between A and B, you get TRUE for that row in your table, otherwise FALSE.

Do `MAX()` to get TRUE if at least one row is TRUE. And if none is TRUE, you'll get FALSE.

(If A can be greater than B, do `between symmetric`.)

Comment: Hi @jarlh, Thanks. I cannot use max because the number ordering is not sequence.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. This will return the result you specified.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/8-UkUBTo